# Size of Tensorflows translation model vs size of dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, dataset, size

I am working with the [translation model](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq) created by tensorflow. My GPU has 12Gb memory, which restricts my model to `size=512`, `num_layers = 2` and `batch_size=32`. As my dataset is from [Ubuntu Dialoge Corpus](http://cs.mcgill.ca/~jpineau/datasets/ubuntu-corpus-1.0/), I got plenty of data. The restrictions, however, makes it impossible to expand the model further and by training on all of the data, the model will probably never converge (underfitting).

Because of the underfitting, I want to limit the training data by slicing away some of it. The question is; how much? Is there a guide line of how much training data a model of a certain size should be fed, in order to converge but avoid overfitting? How many pairs of x_data and y_data can a translation model possible learn from?